# Active Directory with Entity Data Model

Tags: entity-framework, active-directory

Has anyone been able to get access to Active Directory using Entity Data Model?. I read about "LINQ to Active Directory" but it is using outdated LINQ to SQL. And most of the examples I searched through Google reference this Codeplex wrapper. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Entity framework is technology for accessing relational database. There is no provider for Active Directory / LDAP because it is not relational database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found something called [Linq to Active Directory](http://linqtoad.codeplex.com/) on codeplex, which is using LDAP instead of any Linq to SQL mapper. Because Active Directory is based on LDAP rather than SQL I doubt there is a solution using Entity Framework. You shouldn't dismiss this project, since mapping queries to LDAP queries isn't easy and this library seems to do a pretty good job at it.

Is there an Active Directory access provided using a SQL database? I've never heard of it, which doesn't mean that it doesn't exist, but when talking to AD, LDAP is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from
https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/activedirectory-ado-codefirst.rst

> This article shows how to access Active Directory data using an Entity
>   Framework code-first approach. Entity Framework 6 is available in .NET
>   4.5 and above.
>
> Entity Framework is an object-relational mapping framework that can be
>   used to work with data as objects. While you can run the ADO.NET
>   Entity Data Model wizard in Visual Studio to handle generating the
>   Entity Model, this approach, the model-first approach, can put you at
>   a disadvantage if there are changes in your data source or if you want
>   more control over how the entities operate. In this article you will
>   complete the code-first approach to accessing Active Directory data
>   using the CData ADO.NET Provider.

Guess this is the one the article writes about:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.ActiveDirectoryADONETProvider

there's a link to more docs there: 
https://www.cdata.com/drivers/activedirectory/docs/

and eventually found some pricing (not free unfortunately) info here:
https://www.cdata.com/drivers/activedirectory/order/ado/